# Why are dogs descendants of Wolves but humans are not descendants of chimpanzees?

Tags: dogs

From [here](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/evolution/library/01/5/l_015_02.html#:%7E:text=The%20dog%2C%20Canis%20familiaris%2C%20is,Darwin%20was%20wrong%20about%20dogs.)

> The dog, Canis familiaris, is a direct descendent of the gray wolf, Canis lupus:

But from [here](https://www.amnh.org/exhibitions/permanent/human-origins/understanding-our-past/dna-comparing-humans-and-chimps#:%7E:text=Human%20and%20chimp%20DNA%20is,generation%20to%20generation%2C%20changed%20too.)

> Human and chimp DNA is so similar because the two species are so closely related. Humans, chimps and bonobos descended from a single ancestor species that lived six or seven million years ago. As humans and chimps gradually evolved from a common ancestor, their DNA, passed from generation to generation, changed too.

Same is said for cats and dogs that they evolved from a common ancestor that is neither dog nor cat. 
**Why are dogs "friendly wolves"? but humans not " intelligent chimps"? Why are dogs descendants of wolves (with wolf ancestor) but humans and chimpanzees different species (with common ancestor)?**

I don't think reproduction is the basis for this because dogs and wolves don't mate to produce fertile progeny in the wild.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I think, this question would be a better fit in biology.SE, because the sience of descendants belongs there. Also the rule for "child of someone" vs. "descendant race/species" is part of the biology field of science.

Answer (score 11):

The very simplistic answer is that dogs and wolves belong to the same genus and are so closely related that they are often considered to be parts of the same species. The genus is *Canis* (Latin for dog) and the species are *lupus* (Latin for wolf) with domestic dogs being the subspecies *familiaris* (...the familiar one) to make the dog's name *Canis lupus familiaris* and the wolf's *Canis lupus lupus*. Being this closely related, dogs and wolves can interbreed to produce a hybrid [wolfdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfdog), which can themselves be fertile. Fertile interbreeds is one of the characteristics that are used to determine the separation of species. This means that things like [mules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule), which are a cross between a horse (*Equus ferus*) and donkey (*Equus africanus*), and are different species within a genus aren't fertile.

Wikipedia has a good illustration of the relationships between dogs and wolves on the page on the [genus *Canis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canis#Taxonomy). Basically the genomes of dogs and wolves will be very very similar, much more similar than that of humans compared to chimpanzees. The last common ancestor (LCA) of dogs and wolves is about 10,000 years ago, at the domestication of dogs.

On the other hand [Humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human); *Homo sapiens* (Latin for "same" and "wise-one") and [chimpanzees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimpanzee); *Pan troglodites* (Pan was a god of the forest in mythology and Troglodites were mythical cave dwellers), are not even in the same genus, though we are in the same family grouping, known as the [Hominidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominidae), meaning that we are closely related in terms of body shape.

We don't actually have fossil evidence of the LCA for chimps and humans, so we don't know exactly what it looked like. However, for some frame of reference, I refer you to the excellent and informative *[A Short History of Nearly Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Short_History_of_Nearly_Everything)* by Bill Bryson, which has a line on hominid remains which goes something like this:

> If you took all the ancient hominid remains you could comfortably fit them into the back of a pickup truck with room to spare.

While our genomes are similar, the genetic similarity is about 98.8% - which in a genome of about [3.2 billion bases](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21134/), this equates to [about 35 million differences](https://www.amnh.org/exhibitions/permanent/human-origins/understanding-our-past/dna-comparing-humans-and-chimps). The similarity between [wolves and dogs is 99.9%](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-wolf-became-dog/), which, with a genome of 2.4 billion bases, gives about 2.4 million differences, far fewer than between humans and chimpanzees.

The LCA of humans and chimpanzees is about [10-13 million years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimpanzee%E2%80%93human_last_common_ancestor#Age_estimates), which is about 1000x longer than that for dogs and wolves. If you could go forward about another 10 million years, dogs and wolves might be similarly separated to humans and chimpanzees.

Another problem here is the concept of relatedness - the LCA of humans and chimpanzees isn't a chimpanzee or a human, rather it is a species with similarities to both.  On the other hand, we know the LCA of dogs and wolves, and know that it was a wolf, because of their close relationship. Thus we can say that dogs are the wolf's little sibling or are friendly wolves, but we can't say that humans are brainy chimps (or that chimps are less intelligent humans)

Comment: +1 for the balance between details and "understandability" :)

Comment: also wolves is a group which the ancestor of dogs would still definitely be in, while chimpanzee is not even the only Pan species.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Thanks, it's a difficult line to walk and the biologist in me is screaming to add commentary on the not quite true bits

Comment: @John Good point, also not to mention that there are a bunch of other hominina, with many extinct species, of which we are the only surviving species, not just of the genus *Homo* but of all genera within that clade.